# VBA code for plotting graph with given starting point and ending point

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I would like to ask how to create a VBA code to plot a clustered column chart with the given starting point and ending point? I use `inputbox` function to allow the user to state the starting point. For example, the starting point is Jan-20. Then, the code needs to figure out the cell name of the starting point from a set of data, for example, A30. Then the user needs to key in the ending point in order to define the range of data that need to be plotted, for example, Feb-21, which is at the cell A45. Then the data range for the graph should be from `A30:A45, B30:B45`.

I have tried everything I can find online, but nothing quite worked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, show us what you tried, even if it does not do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub createChartChooseSt_EndDate()
   Dim cht As Shape, sh As Worksheet, LastRA As Long, rngPlot As Range
   Dim startP, endP, cellStart As Range, cellEnd As Range
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
   
   LastRA = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   'use the standard date format according to your regional settings:
   startP = InputBox("Please enter the Starting poind date (Format dd/mm/yyyy)", "Choose starting date", Date)
   If Not IsDate(startP) Then MsgBox "No valid date format entered (start)...": Exit Sub
   
   endP = InputBox("Please enter the Ending poind date (Format dd/mm/yyyy)", "Choose ending date", Date + 10)
   If Not IsDate(endP) Then MsgBox "No valid date format entered (end)...": Exit Sub

   'create the range to be plotted:
   'find cellStart:
   Set cellStart = sh.Range("A1:A" & LastRA).Find(what:=CDate(startP), lookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, After:=sh.Range("A1"), SearchDirection:=xlNext)
   If cellStart Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No start date found...": Exit Sub

   'find cellEnd:
   Set cellEnd = sh.Range("A1:A" & LastRA).Find(what:=CDate(endP), lookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, After:=cellStart, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
   If cellEnd Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No end date found...": Exit Sub
   
   Set rngPlot = sh.Range(sh.cells(cellStart.row, 1), sh.cells(cellEnd.row, 2))
   Set cht = sh.Shapes.AddChart
    With cht.Chart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "My custom chart"
        .SetSourceData Source:=rngPlot
        .ChartType = xl3DBarClustered
    End With
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

You can give a name to the created chart and next time you run the code, with some modifications, it may check if the chart exists and only change the data source for the newly chosen date start/ date end...

Comment: @ztee: Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: Hi, it didn't do what I need. As I found that I need the date to be in a row, and the respective data to be on another row. At the same time, inside the excel sheet, there are many repetitive dates, which causes the code to be failed to run.

Comment: @ztee: I cannot get you... The above code offers you the possibility to select which start date, respectively, end date **rows** to be selected according to your input(s). Of course, if the chosen date exists in the A:A column of the active sheet. What do you mean by "there are many repetitive dates"? The chart range is build according to the first (start) date row and the end date row. Doesn't it work in this way? Are your date range sorted? If not, this is what you want? Does the code return a error?

Comment: @ztee: If you will answer after other two days and do not say anything about the code problem, it will be difficult to receive any help. It is at least strange to be **me** more interested in solving of your problem...